# Warning Message in MICE - 93 logged events not collinear or constant problems

Tags: r, r-mice

I am using MICE to impute a dataset including factors and numeric variables, and I don't understand the the output of these logged events or why I am being warned. Please ignore the constant about ethnicity, the variable has no NAs so I did not convert to a factor. Why is the out column showing two levels of religion? What is this warning telling me?

Here is a snippet of the output:

```
   it im  dep     meth           out
1   0  0      constant     ethnicity
2   1  1 Q80P      pmm   religionJew
3   1  1 Q84P      pmm religionHindu
4   1  1 Q85P      pmm religionHindu
5   1  1 Q86P      pmm religionHindu
6   1  2 Q80P      pmm   religionJew
7   1  2 Q84P      pmm religionHindu
8   1  2 Q85P      pmm religionHindu
9   1  2 Q86P      pmm religionHindu
10  1  3 Q80P      pmm   religionJew
```

Here is the code:

```
comp_thesis <- mice(add_all, defaultMethod = c("pmm", 'logreg', 'polyreg', 'polr'), seed = 123, diagnostics = TRUE, print = FALSE)
```

I appreciate any insights into the issue. Thanks

I expected it to run without warnings or errors.